# Phoenix JSON API - configure route to call correct function in controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a logout system which is created in a Phoenix app, where the logout button is in a Phoenix template, as shown by the three code snippets below. This works fine.

Phoenix template: **/web/templates/layout/app.html.eex**

```html
<%= link "Logout", to: auth_path(@conn, :delete), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

Phoenix Routes: **/web/router.ex**

The relevant route is the **delete** route.

```js
scope "/auth", AdminApi do
  pipe_through :browser

  get "/:provider", AuthController, :index
  get "/:provider/callback", AuthController, :callback
  delete "/logout", AuthController, :delete
end
```

Phoenix controller: **/web/controllers/auth_controller.ex**

```js
def delete(conn, _params) do
  conn
  |> put_flash(:info, "You have been logged out!")
  |> configure_session(drop: true)
  |> redirect(to: "/")
end
```

I am trying to implement the same thing, but with a separate frontend and using Phoenix as a JSON API.

The idea is that the frontend makes an AJAX DELETE request to the relevant API endpoint, and the route then catches that call and fires the delete function in the **auth_controller**.

How do I configure the route, so that it will fire the relevant function in the controller?

PS I'm certain it is not a CORS issue, as the CORS plug is working for other routes such as **"/auth/:provider"**

Below is what I have so far:

**AJAX Request from frontend**

```js
var url = ENV.apiProtocol + ENV.apiHost + "/api/auth";
Ember.$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "DELETE",
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response)
  },
  error: function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  }
});
```

Phoenix routes: **/web/router.ex**

```js
scope "/api", AdminApi do
    pipe_through: api

    resources "/auth/:provider", AuthController, except: [:new, :edit]
    resources "/auth", AuthController, except: [:new, :edit]

end
```

Phoenix controller: **/web/controllers/auth_controller.ex**

```js
def delete(conn, _params) do
  conn
  |> put_flash(:info, "You have been logged out!")
  |> configure_session(drop: true)
  |> redirect(to: "/")
end
```

Comment: What part of this is not working? Are you getting any error that you could share?

Comment: The error says "no route found for DELETE /api/auth (AdminApi.Router)"

Comment: If you run `mix phx.routes` is there one listed? Have you tried restarting your phoenix server?

Comment: Yes it shows 
auth_path  DELETE  /api/auth/:id             AdminApi.AuthController :delete
Essentially I'd like to customise the path /api/auth/:id so that I can make a request to a fixed endpoint and fire the delete function.

Comment: That is not the same route. You are not including the `:id` portion, so it will not match.

Comment: Is it possible to customise the endpoint that corresponds to the delete function? For example `/api/auth/logout` instead of `/api/auth/:id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a conflicting route. By using `resources` in that way, you're creating a route which expects an ID to be appended to the end of the path. I.e. `DELETE /api/auth/3`.

You would benefit from having a normal `DELETE /api/auth` or `DELETE /api/session` route where the token you're passing is indicative of the user whose session you'd like to destroy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was defining a resource in the route, and so Phoenix as expecting a DELETE request to be made to the endpoint `/api/auth:id`.

In **web/router.ex** I changed

`resources "/auth", AuthController, except: [:new, :edit]`

to

`delete "auth/logout", AuthController, :delete`

Now an AJAX DELETE request to the endpoint `/api/auth/logout` fires the logout function in auth controller.